# How to add wms overlay layer to google map

Tags: google-maps, mapserver, tiles, google-maps-api

I have a WMS server (using MapServer and Apache on windows). i read [this document](http://mapserver.org/output/tile_mode.html#using-google-maps) about Mapserver's Tile Mode and use that's example to overlay my map on Google maps.but not work.

my code:

```
function load() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    var urlTemplate = 'http://79.175.166.195:1280/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?';
        urlTemplate += 'map=C:\\ms4w\\apps\\Rasht\\RashtMap.map&';
        urlTemplate += 'layers=base street&';
        urlTemplate += 'mode=tile&';
        urlTemplate += 'tilemode=gmap&';
        urlTemplate += 'tile={X}+{Y}+{Z}';
    var myLayer = new GTileLayer(null,0,18,{
                                 tileUrlTemplate:urlTemplate,
                                 isPng:true,
                                 opacity:1.0 });
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.282340, 49.588540), 15);
    map.addOverlay(new GTileLayerOverlay(myLayer));
  }
}
```

what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will never work. You are using code for the deprecated Google Maps API v2. Trying what's happened with the sample, I get a message like below

> Control is no longer supported in the Google Maps Javascript API v2.
>   Please visit
>   developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/v2tov3 to
>   migrate your application to v3.

I didn't dive into the code but there are working examples using WMS everywhere. MapServer can deliver WMS although the code you mentioned relies on the old way to serve MapServer maps (CGI-mode).

Using a search engine, I found various demos like [this one](http://www.sigacts.com/html5/google-maps-api-with-wms-overlay/), [this other](http://www.gisdoctor.com/v3/wms_single_complete.html), [this third demo](http://www.gisdoctor.com/v3/openlayers_wms.html) or [this last one](http://www.sumbera.com/lab/GoogleV3/tiledWMSoverlayGoogleV3.htm) to get hints to make a working example.